# iframe onload is not firing with Edge browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, iframe, angularjs-directive

I have an angular directive to display a PDF report on a model window alone with loading spinner. Problem is **iframe onload** is not firing in **Edge browser**. Basically i need to hide my spinner once PDF is loaded on iframe. I have problem  with only Edge, rest all browsers (IE11, FF, Chrome, Safari) its working fine.

**Here is my directive.**

```js
app.module('app.layout')
        .directive('pdfReport', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    iframesrc: '='
                },
                controller: function($scope) {
                    $scope.showSpinner = false;
                    console.log($scope.showSpinner);

                    $scope.$watch("iframesrc", function(newValue) {
                        if (newValue) {
                            $scope.showSpinner = true;
                            console.log($scope.showSpinner);
                        }
                    });

                    $('#reportIframe').on('load', function() {
                        $scope.showSpinner = false;
                        $scope.$apply();
                        console.log($scope.showSpinner);
                    });

                },
                template: '<div pdf-report-loader show-loader="showSpinner" ngplus-overlay-delay-in="30" ngplus-overlay-delay-out="30" ngplus-overlay-animation="dissolve-animation">' +
                    '<div class="model-spinner"></div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<iframe id="reportIframe"  ng-src="{{iframesrc}}" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;border: solid 1px white;">' +
                    '</iframe>'
            }
        });
```